# Spark: KMeans - ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0\x00\x00'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, libsvm

I'm trying to create a kmeans for the mnist dataset. I have a way it works but it is the dirtiest hack.

My input is an CSV file with 784 (=28*28) values between 0 and 255 per row.

My first attempt was to just read my csv input, convert it to sparse arrays and fit the model with the data. However, the code below throws an error:

```py
data = spark.read.csv("datasets/mnist_test.csv").rdd\
    .map(lambda x : [float(str) for str in x])\
    .toDF()
features = VectorAssembler(inputCols=data.columns, outputCol="features").transform(data).select("features")
kmeans = KMeans().setK(10).setSeed(1)
model = kmeans.fit(features)
```

Output:

```
22/01/25 10:44:41 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 4.0 in stage 113.0 (TID 131)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 619, in main
    process()
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 611, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 259, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/ipykernel_74/2701217925.py", line 2, in <lambda>
  File "/tmp/ipykernel_74/2701217925.py", line 2, in <listcomp>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0\x00\x00'
...
```

My next attempt was to save the dataframe as svm and then load it again:

```py
MLUtils.saveAsLibSVMFile(features.rdd.map(lambda x: LabeledPoint(0, MLLibVectors.fromML(x.features))), './libsvm')
data2 = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(spark.sparkContext, './libsvm').toDF()
kmeans = KMeans().setK(10).setSeed(1)
model = kmeans.fit(features)
```

Output:

```
22/01/25 10:47:06 ERROR Instrumentation: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Column features must be of type equal to one of the following types: [struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>, array<double>, array<float>] but was actually of type struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>.
```

My final (working) attempt was to load the exported partitions with the `spark.read.format("libsvm").load(...)` method:

```py
data3 = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("libsvm/part-00000").select("features")
data3arr = list()
for i in range(5):
    data3arr.append(spark.read.format("libsvm").load("libsvm/part-0000"+str(i)).select("features"))
data3cpl = data3arr[0]
for i in data3arr[1:]:
    data3cpl.union(i)
kmeans = KMeans().setK(10).setSeed(1)
model = kmeans.fit(data3cpl)
```

If I look at the structure, the dataframes look quite similar in their structure. Only that `features` gives me an error on `.show()`:

```py
features.printSchema()
features.show(1,False)
data2.printSchema()
data2.show(1,False)
data3cpl.printSchema()
data3cpl.show(1,False)
```

Output:

```
root
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/daemon.py", line 186, in manager
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/daemon.py", line 74, in worker
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 663, in main
    if read_int(infile) == SpecialLengths.END_OF_STREAM:
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 564, in read_int
    raise EOFError
EOFError

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|features                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|(784,[202,203,204,205,206,207,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,245,258,259,260,261,262,263,264,265,266,267,268,269,270,271,272,273,291,292,293,294,295,296,297,298,299,300,301,326,327,328,329,353,354,355,356,381,382,383,384,408,409,410,411,436,437,438,439,463,464,465,466,491,492,493,518,519,520,521,545,546,547,548,572,573,574,575,576,600,601,602,603,627,628,629,630,631,655,656,657,658,682,683,684,685,686,710,711,712,713,714,738,739,740,741],[84.0,185.0,159.0,151.0,60.0,36.0,222.0,254.0,254.0,254.0,254.0,241.0,198.0,198.0,198.0,198.0,198.0,198.0,198.0,198.0,170.0,52.0,67.0,114.0,72.0,114.0,163.0,227.0,254.0,225.0,254.0,254.0,254.0,250.0,229.0,254.0,254.0,140.0,17.0,66.0,14.0,67.0,67.0,67.0,59.0,21.0,236.0,254.0,106.0,83.0,253.0,209.0,18.0,22.0,233.0,255.0,83.0,129.0,254.0,238.0,44.0,59.0,249.0,254.0,62.0,133.0,254.0,187.0,5.0,9.0,205.0,248.0,58.0,126.0,254.0,182.0,75.0,251.0,240.0,57.0,19.0,221.0,254.0,166.0,3.0,203.0,254.0,219.0,35.0,38.0,254.0,254.0,77.0,31.0,224.0,254.0,115.0,1.0,133.0,254.0,254.0,52.0,61.0,242.0,254.0,254.0,52.0,121.0,254.0,254.0,219.0,40.0,121.0,254.0,207.0,18.0])|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
only showing top 1 row

root
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- label: double (nullable = true)

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+
|features                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |label|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+
|(778,[202,203,204,205,206,207,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,245,258,259,260,261,262,263,264,265,266,267,268,269,270,271,272,273,291,292,293,294,295,296,297,298,299,300,301,326,327,328,329,353,354,355,356,381,382,383,384,408,409,410,411,436,437,438,439,463,464,465,466,491,492,493,518,519,520,521,545,546,547,548,572,573,574,575,576,600,601,602,603,627,628,629,630,631,655,656,657,658,682,683,684,685,686,710,711,712,713,714,738,739,740,741],[84.0,185.0,159.0,151.0,60.0,36.0,222.0,254.0,254.0,254.0,254.0,241.0,198.0,198.0,198.0,198.0,198.0,198.0,198.0,198.0,170.0,52.0,67.0,114.0,72.0,114.0,163.0,227.0,254.0,225.0,254.0,254.0,254.0,250.0,229.0,254.0,254.0,140.0,17.0,66.0,14.0,67.0,67.0,67.0,59.0,21.0,236.0,254.0,106.0,83.0,253.0,209.0,18.0,22.0,233.0,255.0,83.0,129.0,254.0,238.0,44.0,59.0,249.0,254.0,62.0,133.0,254.0,187.0,5.0,9.0,205.0,248.0,58.0,126.0,254.0,182.0,75.0,251.0,240.0,57.0,19.0,221.0,254.0,166.0,3.0,203.0,254.0,219.0,35.0,38.0,254.0,254.0,77.0,31.0,224.0,254.0,115.0,1.0,133.0,254.0,254.0,52.0,61.0,242.0,254.0,254.0,52.0,121.0,254.0,254.0,219.0,40.0,121.0,254.0,207.0,18.0])|0.0  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+
only showing top 1 row

root
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|features                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|(776,[202,203,204,205,206,207,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,245,258,259,260,261,262,263,264,265,266,267,268,269,270,271,272,273,291,292,293,294,295,296,297,298,299,300,301,326,327,328,329,353,354,355,356,381,382,383,384,408,409,410,411,436,437,438,439,463,464,465,466,491,492,493,518,519,520,521,545,546,547,548,572,573,574,575,576,600,601,602,603,627,628,629,630,631,655,656,657,658,682,683,684,685,686,710,711,712,713,714,738,739,740,741],[84.0,185.0,159.0,151.0,60.0,36.0,222.0,254.0,254.0,254.0,254.0,241.0,198.0,198.0,198.0,198.0,198.0,198.0,198.0,198.0,170.0,52.0,67.0,114.0,72.0,114.0,163.0,227.0,254.0,225.0,254.0,254.0,254.0,250.0,229.0,254.0,254.0,140.0,17.0,66.0,14.0,67.0,67.0,67.0,59.0,21.0,236.0,254.0,106.0,83.0,253.0,209.0,18.0,22.0,233.0,255.0,83.0,129.0,254.0,238.0,44.0,59.0,249.0,254.0,62.0,133.0,254.0,187.0,5.0,9.0,205.0,248.0,58.0,126.0,254.0,182.0,75.0,251.0,240.0,57.0,19.0,221.0,254.0,166.0,3.0,203.0,254.0,219.0,35.0,38.0,254.0,254.0,77.0,31.0,224.0,254.0,115.0,1.0,133.0,254.0,254.0,52.0,61.0,242.0,254.0,254.0,52.0,121.0,254.0,254.0,219.0,40.0,121.0,254.0,207.0,18.0])|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
only showing top 1 row
```

**Can anyone tell me how to properly convert my data so I can feed it into my kmeans fit?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering because i had a similar issue and in this post i didn't find any solution.
In my case, the problem was caused by a `filter` operation on a `DataFrame`.

I solved calling `cache()` in that DataFrame.

In this case then, one possible solution is to try to cache the RDD:

```
data = spark.read.csv("datasets/mnist_test.csv").rdd\
    .map(lambda x : [float(str) for str in x]).cache()\
    .toDF()
features = VectorAssembler(inputCols=data.columns, outputCol="features").transform(data).select("features")
kmeans = KMeans().setK(10).setSeed(1)
model = kmeans.fit(features)
```